# Is ubuntu phone for android devices only?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone

I have a palm pixi plus and I would be delighted to install ubuntu phone software on my phone.

palm pixi plus phone specifications:

- 600mz processor
- 256mb ram
- 8gb storage space

Comment: The phone system requirements are on [this page](http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/phone/operators-and-oems).